# How to ask someone to move from their seat?

Tags: word-request, register

For example, if there was a sofa in the room, and there were 3 people sitting on it, and there was a little space between their seat. How do you ask them to "move" or to "come close" to each other so that I can fit in, and have a seat with them?

Note: It's that one word that I'm looking for here that I used to know that you can use in this particular situation, but unfortunately, I'm non-native English speaker, that's why sometimes, I forget some words; It is used when you want to ask your seatmate to **move** to that empty space, or something like that.

Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you wanted *scoot over*.

> 1. [scoot](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scoot)
>      2 : to slide especially while seated <*scoot over and let me sit down*>
> 2. [scoot over](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/scoot+over)
>      Move to the side, especially to make room. For example, *If you scoot over a little I'll have room to sit down.*

Comment: Usage note: this would be recognised in the US but is uncommon in the UK.

Answer (score 4):

In the UK one would normally ask somebody to **[hutch up](http://lingodictionary.com/slang-definition/16964/slang-definition-of-hutch-up)**, **shuffle up** or **shuffle along** (all of these are polite but informal) or **move over**- more formal but slightly less polite, or **[shove over](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/shove-over)** which is neither formal nor polite.

Comment: Or you could ask "May I squeeze in beside you?" or "Do you think there is room for another?", which should prompt the sitters to move up.

Answer (score 2):

> [**budge up**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/budge_up#English)

works, meaning:

> To move or scoot over in order to make room for someone, especially when sitting.

Comment: Usage note: this would be recognised in the UK. I suspect it is uncommon in the US.

Answer (score 1):

I want to be a bit informal on this one and to wider the usage. Here are examples I often see and read.

- **make space**
- **move over**
- **move aside**
- **shove over**
- **move off**
- **scooch over**
- **scoot over**
- **give me some room**

Comment: or move up, move over https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/move-over?q=move+over