# How to express this action in English? Could you sit further to the side?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

OK, look at this picture

[image]

The man is sitting in the middle of the sofa & you want to sit next to him on the right (as depicted in the picture).

> **[out of the way](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/way_1#way_idmg_48)** ​  no longer stopping somebody from moving or doing something
>
> I moved my legs out of the way so that she could get past.
>
> I didn't say anything until Dad was out of the way.

**How would you say to him?**

**-Could you sit further to the side?**

**-Could you move further to the side?**

**-Could you move your body further to the side?**

**-Could you move out of the way?** (is it rude to say like this?)

**-Could you move your body out of the way?** (is it rude to say like this?)

Comment: Related/duplicate: [How to ask someone to move from their seat?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/109290/36187)

Comment: A lot depends on how well you know the man.  Is this a stranger? Or is this your brother? Then what is the context? Are you on a train? or are at a party.  Finally what are you like? Are you confident or shy?  There are so many variations.

Comment: We wouldn't use _out of the way_ in this context (not because it would be rude, it's just not appropriate). If you don't know the man well, "Would you mind moving up?" is probably the most polite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask the man to [scoot over](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/scoot-over).

Comment: "Can you scooch over" sounds the most idiomatic to me, but this page has an entire list: https://dare.wisc.edu/surveys/survey-results/1965-1970/physical-actions/y52/

Comment: As mentioned in Em's link, _scoot over_ is American - I've never heard it in the UK.